# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. in Ionic/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-sdk-2.3

IONIC INFO

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v7.10.1
npm  : 4.2.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

The following error is occurring

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: `ANDROID_HOME : not set` have you set the environment variable?

Comment: I haven't set the environment variable. Will adding it resolve the issue ? @SurajRao

Comment: looks like it.. go through the logs and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a recent Cordova issue.
Adding this plugin solved the issue in my case:

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release